# MVC-4 Change ViewBag.Message on server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am beginner in MVC coding.
 When the application starts,  the ViewBag.Message is: Choose a file to upload.

After a successful upload, it changes to: File uploaded successfully!

Is there a way I can make it to return and show the "Choose a file to upload" message again after around 5 seconds, without using any javascript ?
 I thought if mvc had some built in time function I could use maybe ?

https://github.com/xoxotw/mvc_fileUploader

My view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FileUpload";
}

<h2>FileUpload</h2>

<h3>Upload a File:</h3>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
    { 
        @Html.ValidationSummary();
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload" />  
        @ViewBag.Message
    }
```

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mvc_fileUploader.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Choose a file to upload!";
            return View("FileUpload");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase fileToUpload)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (fileToUpload != null && fileToUpload.ContentLength > (1024 * 1024 * 1))  // 1MB limit
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("fileToUpload", "Your file is to large. Maximum size allowed is 1MB !");
                }

                else
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload.FileName);
                    string directory = Server.MapPath("~/fileUploads/");

                    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                    }

                    string path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
                    fileToUpload.SaveAs(path);

                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully!";
                }
            }

                return View("FileUpload");

        }



        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use javascript for this. Why are you looking for a non javascript solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is **No**. I am guessing because you are "new" you want to focus on the MVC part but MVC and JavaScript are very much interlinked, think client (JavaScript) and server (MVC) and you should really master both to make good websites.

Normally the server doesn't fire events to the browser and instead the browser would make the requests. There are ways to get the server to raise events on the client using things like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) but that would be overkill in this scenario.

Finally... what you are trying to achieve is very much a client-side action, i.e. To inform the user to do something. If you did it in MVC you would waste network bandwidth and add delays (think of server calls as expensive) when really it is a client action and so should be done in JavaScript.

Don't shy away from JavaScript. Embrace it. Look into [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) that takes a lot of the heavy lifting away for you.

Comment: Thank you, very good answer, I know what to look into now. ^_^

Comment: You are welcome @xoxo_tw and happy learning! You'll find **StackOverflow** an invaluable resource, I have / do!